# Get content within a tag using Javascript from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get

I want a javascript code which will go through all the html file in my root folder and sub-folders and gets the content which are within a particular tag,
eg:

```
<div id="content">
!!this content!!
</div>
```

It should check for a comment at the top of html and only get the content if it exist.

> <!--Allowed-->

It should only get if this is there. First of all is this possible? I wish jquery could do this!

Update:
Got enlightened that javascript is for client-side! So One last question, how does you use php to get the content that is within the a particular tag?

```
    <div id="content">
    !!this content!!
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you have to get all the folders that are in the folder (on the server). That's not possible with JavaScript alone. You have to write a PHP (or any other web-language supported on your webspace/server) which gives you the filename-list.
Then you can load each file with jQuery's ajax-functions and test for your comment, etc.

Comment: "That's not possible with JavaScript " That is [not entirely true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript).

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I don't expect him to use server-side JS.

Comment: Oh..I forgot that entirely!!! Server side and Client side!! But just out of curiosity does all server support server side js?

Comment: I never really used server-side JS myself, but as far as I know: no.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has no access to the file system. You need a server side language to do that.

Comment: "Javascript has no access to the file system. " Not necessarily true. See other posts.

Comment: Note that the question says "...from HTML", not server side javascript. :)

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible with javascript.  It is a client side scripting language.  You need a serverside scripting language like PHP.  Check out http://php.net/ look up the `fopen()`, `include()`, and `dir()` functions.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the exact content of the comment you're searching for, try this:

```
if(document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf('<!--Comment-->') > 0){
    //voila!
}
```

If not, you can use regular expressions to parse the text. I'm not an expert in regex, so i can't say i can help you there.

Of course, this will only work on a per-page basis, it won't browse your file system. For that you should have a server-side language.
Hope this helps